# find the slist value which is the value for a specific key in map

Tags: c++, list, dictionary

I have a map with a int as the key and a slist as the value. slist is singly linked link list. (like https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Slist.html) 
how do I get the specific slist for the key that I am looking in the map.

the code is below:

```
struct ListElemnts{
int a;
string b;
};

slist<ListElemnts *> element;

typedef std::map<int,slist<ListElemnts *> > hashmapList;

struct ListElemnts* pElement = (struct ListElemnts*) malloc(sizeof(struct ListElemnts));

hashmapList.insert(pair<int , slist<ListElemnts *> >(2,pElement));
hashmapList.insert(pair<int , slist<ListElemnts *> >(1,pElement));

map<int , slist<ListElemnts*> >::iterator it = hashmapList.begin();
it = hashmapList.find(1);
if (it != hashmapList.end())
{ 
  //how do i get the slist for the 'it' i find and assign it to the below slsist to iterate via it
  slist<ListElemnts *>::iterator position;
}
```

how to get the slist for the specific it key??

Comment: Certainly not c code. Stop tag spamming please!

Comment: the code that I posted was C++ code

Comment: And why did you add the [tag:c] tag then?

Comment: sorry my mistake for tagging c

Comment: How about reading the documentation? What was unclear?

Comment: I get an error when I do: slist<ListElemnts *> element = NULL; no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "std::slist. how do I iniatialize the slist to nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get the slist for the specific it key??

Like following:

```
slist<ListElemnts *>::iterator position = it->second.begin();
```

Comment: how would I get the values in it->second. would it be *(it->second).a and *(it->second).b?? since the values of the map is an slist.

Answer (score 0):

1. element._push_front(pElement);
   hashmapList.insert(pair >(2,element)); 
        or
2. hashmapList.insert(pair >(2,pElement));